# Google Chrome Extension: How can I view a background page via an iframe on the popup page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been trying for a while now and can't get this to work.
Basically, when the extension is enabled, I want a persistent page (That will hold a socket connection regardless of whether the Browser Action icon is clicked).

The background page functions in this way. Now, I want this background page to show in the popup page (via iframe or any alternative so that it's not another instance of the Background page.

I get something like this when I try:
"The webpage at chrome-extension://invalid/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Any ideas on a direction I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real background page is hidden, and cannot be shown (the Dev Tools for the background page can be opened by clicking on the `background.html` link at `chrome://extensions/`, in Developer mode).

From the popup, you can directly access methods and properties from the background page, using [`chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getBackgroundPage). This can be used to maintain a (session-)persistent state of your extension's popup window.

When you try to load the background page in a frame/tab, a *new* instance of the page is shown. This, however, is **not** a background page. It's treated as a normal HTML file within your extension.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the url for the background page I'd recommend using `chrome.extension.getURL('background.html')`

But I don't recommend this method for what you're doing, though I suppose it would work. I would instead recommend using some simple message passing. With this, you're popup/browser action will actually hold your html for your UI, and send a message to the background page asking for the live web socket stuff from the background page.

These are the docs on message passing: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html

Have fun and good luck! It's not bad at all, let me know if you have questions though