# Opening the background page of a chrome extension from an already running proccess

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I'm currently coding my first chrome extension which runs youtube.com/tv in a background process so you can always accesses it with a phone or table, this is working fine but if you want to view the video not just hear the audio I have to open the page which the background process is on, and this is where the problems start, because opening the new page creates a second process which conflicts with the first instant crashing them both, so i need to know if there is a way to open the background instance into a view able tab.
Code Below:

### manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Youtube TV",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "A simple extension which runs 'www.youtube.com/tv' in the background of your browser do you can connect to it with your phone whenever your computer is turned on.",
  "background": {
    "persistent": true,
    "page": "background.html",
    "script": "background.js"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

### background.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:0px">
    <script src="background.js"></script>
    <iframe style="margin:0px; border:0px" src="http://youtube.com/tv" width="100%" height="100%" >
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

### background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  function (details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() == 'x-frame-options') {
        details.responseHeaders.splice(i, 1);
        return {
          responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders
        };
      }
    }
  }, {
    urls: ["<all_urls>"]
  }, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(
  function (activeTab) {
    var newURL = "http://youtube.com/tv";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Extension: How can I view a background page via an iframe on the popup page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116218/google-chrome-extension-how-can-i-view-a-background-page-via-an-iframe-on-the-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('background.html')});
```

EDIT
Sorry i didnt properly understand the question. See the answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116218/google-chrome-extension-how-can-i-view-a-background-page-via-an-iframe-on-the-p)

> The real background page is hidden, and cannot be shown

Comment: This opens a _copy_ of the background page. OP expressly stated that this creates a conflict.